# How to insert utf8 to db with sql connection in python?

Tags: python

I have:

```
`varib = "còn tèn"`
```

After insert, in the db showing:

```
`'c\xc3\xb2n t\xc3\xa8n'`
```

But I want to write `còn tèn` in my db. What to do?

Comment: Is this python2 or python3? What DB/libraries are being used? With or without sqlalchemy? We can't help you with such limited details.

Comment: `"'c\xc3\xb2n t\xc3\xa8n'"` _is_ "còn tèn", it's just encoded as utf8. You just need to decode to unicode when you read the data back.

Comment: I use python2 and sql connection.

Comment: Still not enough information to go on. Which db engine are you connection to, and with which library? How are you viewing the UTF8 data in the database?

Comment: I'm sorry, but now i want to ask other question. I have a dict foo = {}, foo['nd'] = bar (bar = "thắc mắc"). I print(foo), it showing {'nd':'th\xe1\xba\xafc m\xe1\xba\xafc'}. I want to show {'nd': 'thắc mắc'}. I use python 2.7. Please help me fix it!